# can my employer track my internet use on my personal computer?

Tags: privacy

I am a telecommuter.  My employer supplied a computer and pays a cable company for a modem and internet service.  If i connect my personal router and my personal laptop to that modem, can they track me?  This is a laptop never used for work.

Comment: possibly. How are we supposed to know? We didn't build that router, and we haven't read your contract, and we don't know your local rules on that. But it's not unlikely that your access might be always going through a VPN to your company's main network – in which case, all your traffic would go through the same infrastructure that it would go through if you were at the company's premises.

Comment: Do they have the capability? Yes. Are they doing it? We can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, it is impossible to know for sure without knowing more information. Even knowing the router they supplied might help.

For example, if they supplied a professional-grade router such as a CISCO, it is really quite likely that they have configured the router to do at least some monitoring in order to help secure the connection.

Even without that, the router may be configured to pass all traffic back through the corporate network in which case, it is almost certain that they would monitor access and traffic.

You may already have the information you need to work this out. Did IT tell you whether your laptop would have to use a VPN connection or a secure token of some kind to connect to the corporate services? If that happens on the laptop itself, it at least means that the router isn't configured as a VPN end point - if that were the case, anything you connect to it would enter an encrypted, virtual "pipe" to the organisations data centre.